# hibernate not populating collection but query matches

Tags: sql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a hierarchy of objects in hibernate.  I am simply printing the hierarchy out by looping through the hierarchy.

Everything prints out great until I get to the bottom of the hierarchy.  I have a Group object which has a collection of Artifact objects.  I set up by hibernate mapping to retrieve a Set of artifacts for the Group object.  I did this on a column called ratio as opposed to the id column.  The Group object has 1 to many relationship with the artifacts.  Both objects have the ratio field.

The Group mapping looks like so:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Group" table="Group">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="ratio" type="string"></property>
          <set name="artifacts" table="Artifact" 
                inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="ratio" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="Artifact" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The Artifact mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Artifact" table="Artifact">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="ratio" type="string"></property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The problem is that group objects print out, but the artifacts do not return anything in the queries.  I have printed the ratio returned from each group.  I have then copied the sql statement out put hibernate outputs and substituted the ratio in the where statement criteria and everything returns correctly:

```
 select artifact0_.ratio as rat2_3_1_, artifact0_.id as id1_, artifact0_.id as id4_0_, artifact0_.ratio as rat2_4_0_from Artifact artifact0_ where artifact0_.ratio='1'
```

Does anyone know why the hibernate collection is not returning anything?

Comment: is the db column for ratio by any chance char(n)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your statement executes correctly in sql with the ratio parameter substituted but is does not do when executed by Hibernate, then this is because you've substituted a different value than Hibernate actually has. You can use a tool like log4jdbc to see the actual values of the parameters in the generated SQL statement.

The problem in your mapping is: In the set you define the key as `ratio`. This makes `ratio` the foreign key in the table `Artifact` and joins it with the key of the parent, which is `Group.id` (and not `Group.ratio` as you've probably intended).

There are two solutions:

1. You define `ratio` as the unique key in `Group`. Then in your mapping `Artifact.ratio` is joined to `Group.ratio`.
2. If you can't do 1. because `ratio` is not unique in `Group` (or if you do not want to do 1.), then the relation between `Group` and `Artifact` is a many to many relation, and you should use the `<many-to-many>` tag. Here you have the properties `column` and `property-ref` to name the join columns in both tables.

Comment: Ratio is a unique key in the Group table.  Is there something I can do in the mapping to ensure that they both join on ratio?

Comment: Then you can define ´ratio´ as the primary key. Or you use many-to-many even if it is logically only a one-to-many relation. Or you do not define the relation in Hibernate and in the method `Group.getArtifactList()` you manually load the artifacts in a separate HQL statement.